# Making a variable that takes a value from an input available in lexical scope. javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, scope, global, lexical

I'm having trouble understanding why I can't get the ( name ) variable that is placed in the global scope here to be available to my function greeting1()'s lexical scope. I want to use those values for all functions and don't want to have to keep writing that in each function. Does this have something to do with the value just not getting stored in the value before I click the submit button and that's why it's returning an empty string as firstname and lastname values?

```
const firstname = $('#firstname').val();
const lastname = $('#lastname').val();
let name = G$(firstname, lastname);

 // example using jQueryGreet()
var greeting1 = function () {

const lang = $('#lang').val();

name.setLang(lang).jQueryGreet('#greeting', true).log();
console.log(name);

}

//example using vanillaGreet()
var greeting2 = function () {

const lang = document.getElementById('lang').value;

name.setLang(lang).vanillaGreet('#greeting').log();

}

$('#login').click(greeting1);
```

it works when I put the firstname, lastname, and name variables inside the functions but not when I take them out.

also, nevermind the G$() and other weird looking functions. they are just a library that i'm building to practice.

Comment: Is `name` returning an object that has the `setLang` method on it ? Also the way the code is written `name` is an object and when you log it would just dump the object def.

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: and yes to the second part too. When i log it, it has the first and last name as empty strings. but when I put the firstname,lastname, and name variables inside the functions it works fine. i'm guessing the js engine isnt picking up the values typed before calling the function

Comment: so it actually is recognizing the name variable, its just that the values from firstname and lastname aren't getting put into name when i call the function